# Avoid ISODate() in MongoDB aggregation framework so pipeline can be pure JSON

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation pipeline like this in MongoDB:

```
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "event": "LOG_ACCESS",
      "createdAt": {
        "$gte": ISODate("2023-01-24T00:00:00+00:00"),
        "$lt": ISODate("2023-01-25T00:00:00+00:00")
      }
    }
  }
]
```

That works, but I wonder if I can reformulate it using pure JSON syntax (note that `ISODate()` doesn't conform with JSON syntax). I have checked the [MongoDB extended JSON](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) and the [`$date`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#mongodb-bsontype-Date) operator looks nice, so I tryed:

```
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "event": "LOG_ACCESS",
      "createdAt": {
        "$gte": {"$date": "2023-01-24T00:00:00+00:00"},
        "$lt": {"$date": "2023-01-25T00:00:00+00:00"}
      }
    }
  }
]
```

but it doesn't work. I get this error:

> Field must not begin with '$' or '.', field path was: $date

Is there any way of expressing the above query in pure JSON?

Thanks in advance for your feedback!

Comment: A JSON supports only strings, numbers,boolean and null. Thus a `Date` object can never be part of a strict JSON object. Maybe tell us, why (you think that) you can use only pure JSON in your application. As far as I know, all drivers provides a way to create a BSON `Date` object. In fact, MongoDB works with BSON, rather than JSON.

Comment: Because I take the aggregation pipeline from a REST API and it comes as a pure JSON. Of course, I can do JSON-to-MongoAPI conversions in my endpoint, but it makes mi API implementation more complex, so I wonder if a direct approach is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know `$date` is not used for querying/aggregations, but you should be able to use `$toDate`. It's important to note that you also need to wrap the conversion to a date in an expression.

Example:

```
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "event": "LOG_ACCESS",
            "$expr": {
                "$and": [
                    {"$gte": ["$createdAt", {"$toDate": "2023-01-24T00:00:00+00:00"}]},
                    {"$lte": ["$createdAt", {"$toDate": "2023-01-25T00:00:00+00:00"}]}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`ISODate` is an alias in the mongo shell for  `new Date()`, try

```
new Date("2023-01-24T00:00:00+00:00")
```

Comment: I'm afraid it has the same problem... I cannot use `new Date(...)` a value in a JSON (JSON value only allows strings, numbers, bools, objetct and array)

Answer (score 0):

For the records (and although I prefer [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75257555/1485926)) this also works (but requires two stages):

```
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "year": { "$year": "$createdAt" },
      "month": { "$month": "$createdAt" },
      "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$createdAt" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "event": "LOG_ACCESS"
      "month": 1,
      "year": 2023,
      "day": 24
    }
  }
]
```